# Why am i getting peewee.OperationalError

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, orm, peewee

I am trying to add 'items', 'price', 'stock' and eventually 'dates' into my inventory.db using the table called Product. How do I get that data in there without bombing the code. Since I'm new to this type of stuff please go into detail on what I'm doing wrong.

Also how can I make an ID for each individual product name?  I've been looking and I just don't see what I'm looking for.

Here's what I'm working with: https://github.com/OXDavidXO/Python-Project-4/blob/main/app.py.

Here's the part that is messing up:

```py
inventory = {
    'items': food_names,
    'price': food_price,
    'stock': food_stock,
    'dates': dates_added
}


def add_products():

    try:
        food_item = Product.create(product_names = inventory['items'])
        food_item.save()
    except IntegrityError:
        food_product = Product.get(product_names = inventory['items'])
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include the _complete_ error traceback.

Comment: What do you mean by "bombing the code"? Since you appear to be new to this, I would recommend just doing a simple `for` loop and calling `Product.create()` for each individual product you want to add. Don't worry about optimizations (e.g. bulk create) until you get a basic implementation working.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you are using Postgresql, although you didn't mention what db. When you get into a bad transactional state (e.g. by catching the integrity error) then you need to rollback to a good state to continue. The proper way is to:

```
try:
    with db.atomic() as tx:
        food_item = Product.create(product_names = inventory['items'])
        # calling save() again is redundant, removed.
except IntegrityError as exc:
    food_item = Product.get(product_names = inventory['items'])
```

Otherwise, please post the actual traceback and error message. It is hard to debug without this information.